# Hazelcast instance discorvery running in embeded mode inside azure app service

Tags: azure, spring-boot, hazelcast, azure-web-app-service

I've spring boot app with hazelcast IMDG 3.11.1 running in azure app service scaled out to 4 instances.

**`1. build.gradle dependencies`**

```
compile 'com.hazelcast:hazelcast-azure:1.2.1'
compile 'com.hazelcast:hazelcast:3.11.1'
compile 'com.hazelcast:hazelcast-spring:3.11.1'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
```

tried with hazelcast-azure discovery plugin 
**`2. hazelcast.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hazelcast
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config/hazelcast-config-3.10.xsd"
  xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <group>
        <name>${hazelcast.environment.name}</name>
        <password>${hazelcast.environment.password}</password>
    </group>
    <properties>
        <property name="hazelcast.discovery.enabled">true</property>
    </properties>
    <network>
        <port auto-increment="false">5701</port>
        <join>
            <tcp-ip enabled="false" />
            <multicast enabled="false"/>
            <aws enabled="false" />
            <discovery-strategies>
                <!-- class equals to the DiscoveryStrategy not the factory! -->
                <discovery-strategy enabled="true" class="com.hazelcast.azure.AzureDiscoveryStrategy">
                    <properties>
                        <property name="client-id">${platform.azure.client-id}</property>
                        <property name="client-secret">${platform.azure.client-secret}</property>
                        <property name="tenant-id">${platform.azure.client-domain}</property>
                        <property name="subscription-id">${platform.azure.subscription}</property>
                        <property name="cluster-id">${hazelcast.environment.name}</property>
                        <property name="group-name">${hazelcast.environment.name}</property>
                    </properties>
                </discovery-strategy>
            </discovery-strategies>
        </join>
    </network>
...
My Map list
...
</hazelcast>
```

Dug deep in azure plugin allows to discover dedicated cluster i.e. client-server mode of hazelcast cluster.

Is there any way of enabling cluster node discovery for hazelcast nodes running in embeded mode inside a azure app service?

Answer (score 0):

@Mr.Arjun, not right now but I’m creating a new verison of Azure Discovery plugin for Hazelcast which uses Azure REST APIs & would love to add this feature as well ( working for Hazelcast). Can you please open a github issue for this in hazelcast azure github repo: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-azure